# How would I use the user uploaded image as the background image for the sliding puzzle I am working on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to make it so that when a user uploads the image file it is automatically used as the background image in the puzzle. I have tried looking up how I would do that and I feel like it would be that hard but I'm just having a brain fart. I am also looking to start a timer once the image gets uploaded but I feel like that is something I ould probably be able to figure out myself but any tips would certainly be appreciated.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="functions.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css" type="text/css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Puzzle</title>

    </head> 

    <body>

        <div class="file-upload">
        <input class="file-upload__input" type="file" name="picture" id="picture" accept="image/*">
        <button class="file-upload__button" type="button">Choose a Photo</button>
        <span class="file-upload__label"></span>
     </div>

<!--button formating-->
        <script>
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".file-upload__button"), function(button) {
                const hiddenInput = button.parentElement.querySelector(".file-upload__input");
                const label = button.parentElement.querySelector(".file-upload__label");
                const defaultLabelText = "No file(s) selected";

                // Set default text for label
                label.textContent = defaultLabelText;
                label.title = defaultLabelText;

                button.addEventListener('click', function(){
                    hiddenInput.click();
                });
                hiddenInput.addEventListener('change', function(){
                    const filenameList = Array.prototype.map.call(hiddenInput.files, function (file){
                        return file.name;
                    });
                    label.textContent = filenameList.join(', ') || defaultLabelText;
                    label.title = label.textContent;
                });
            });
        </script>
<!--Puzzle-->
<center><div id="table" style="display: table;">
    <div id="row1" style="display: table-row;">
       <div id="cell11" class="tile1" onClick="clickTile(1,1);"></div>
       <div id="cell12" class="tile2" onClick="clickTile(1,2);"></div>
       <div id="cell13" class="tile3" onClick="clickTile(1,3);"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="row2" style="display: table-row;">
       <div id="cell21" class="tile4" onClick="clickTile(2,1);"></div>
       <div id="cell22" class="tile5" onClick="clickTile(2,2);"></div>
       <div id="cell23" class="tile6" onClick="clickTile(2,3);"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="row3" style="display: table-row;">
       <div id="cell31" class="tile7" onClick="clickTile(3,1);"></div>
       <div id="cell32" class="tile8" onClick="clickTile(3,2);"></div>
       <div id="cell33" class="tile9" onClick="clickTile(3,3);"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
   <button onClick="shuffle();">New Game</button>
 </center>
</body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
body { 
    background: #002a3f;
    }
.file-upload {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 20px;

}
.file-upload__input {
    display: none;
}

.file-upload__button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #009879;
    border: 2px solid #00745d;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0.5em 0.8em;
    margin-right: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.file-upload__button:active{
    background: #00745d;
}

.file-upload__label{
    max-width: 250px;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

    .tile1, .tile2, .tile3, .tile4, .tile5, .tile6, .tile7, .tile8, .tile9 {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      border: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
      background: url(); 
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .tile1 {background-position: left top;}
    .tile2 {background-position: center top;}
    .tile3 {background-position: right top;}
    .tile4 {background-position: left center;}
    .tile5 {background-position: center center;}
    .tile6 {background-position: right center;}
    .tile7 {background-position: left bottom;}
    .tile8 {background-position: center bottom;}
    .tile9 {background: rgb(58, 58, 58); cursor: default;}
```

JS:

```
function swapTiles(cell1,cell2) {
    var temp = document.getElementById(cell1).className;
    document.getElementById(cell1).className = document.getElementById(cell2).className;
    document.getElementById(cell2).className = temp;
  }

  function shuffle() {
  //Use nested loops to access each cell of the 3x3 grid
  for (var row=1;row<=3;row++) { //For each row of the 3x3 grid
     for (var column=1;column<=3;column++) { //For each column in this row

      var row2=Math.floor(Math.random()*3 + 1); //Pick a random row from 1 to 3
      var column2=Math.floor(Math.random()*3 + 1); //Pick a random column from 1 to 3

      swapTiles("cell"+row+column,"cell"+row2+column2); //Swap the look & feel of both cells
    } 
  } 
  }

  function clickTile(row,column) {
    var cell = document.getElementById("cell"+row+column);
    var tile = cell.className;
    if (tile!="tile9") { 
         //Checking if white tile on the right
         if (column<3) {
           if ( document.getElementById("cell"+row+(column+1)).className=="tile9") {
             swapTiles("cell"+row+column,"cell"+row+(column+1));
             return;
           }
         }
         //Checking if white tile on the left
         if (column>1) {
           if ( document.getElementById("cell"+row+(column-1)).className=="tile9") {
             swapTiles("cell"+row+column,"cell"+row+(column-1));
             return;
           }
         }
           //Checking if white tile is above
         if (row>1) {
           if ( document.getElementById("cell"+(row-1)+column).className=="tile9") {
             swapTiles("cell"+row+column,"cell"+(row-1)+column);
             return;
           }
         }
         //Checking if white tile is below
         if (row<3) {
           if ( document.getElementById("cell"+(row+1)+column).className=="tile9") {
             swapTiles("cell"+row+column,"cell"+(row+1)+column);
             return;
           }
         } 
    }

  }
```

Comment: Do you know you can use the image from input without uploading? Just sayin', because maybe you actually want the user to upload his image to store it.

Comment: how would I do this?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: By the way, it's funny, because a few days ago I made my own sliding puzzle with user's image :D

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction thank you! but I'm still kind of confused on how I can change it so that it is able to reference the image in the CSS as the background image for the tiles.

Comment: You need to use that `readAsDataURL()` method as `element.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + dataUrl + ')'`. My puzzle game used canvas, but you're good to go with `background-image` as well.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still lost. I think I've been looking at this too much today and might just need to take a break.

Comment: I think that's a good idea. It's definitely not trivial, as you need to use a couple of event listeners. But it's worth it if you don't care for user's file, because they won't need to wait even one second for your game. I'm here for you tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use client's image without ever uploading it. The way to do that is to use `FileReader API`. Check out Mozilla's tutorial of [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL).